# How are texlive-latex-extra Styles Used in Debian Jessie

Tags: packages

I have the `texlive-latex-extra` package which the supplies the background style:

```
$ dpkg -L texlive-latex-extra | grep background
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/background
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/background/background.sty
```

I'm running Debian Jessie.

Attempting to use the "background" style results in an error:

foo.tex:

```
...
\usepackage(background)
...
```

build command:

```
pdflatex foo.tex
```

result:

```
! LaTex Error: File `(.sty' not found.
```

Similar results are obtained for all other styles in the `texlive-latex-extra` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that the macro parser expects an argument - a balanced group `{`..`}` after `\usepackage`. If this doesn't happen, it assumes the first token - `(` in this case - represents the argument. And no package `(.sty` exists, resulting in the error you see.

The correct syntax for package inclusion is

```
\usepackage{<package>}
```

and *not*

```
\usepackage(<package>)
```

Arguments in (La)TeX are passed using `{`..`}` in general, not `(`..`)`.

Comment: Wow. I guess I should have mentioned I'm new to Latex.

Comment: Nice explanation of the error message.